# What is the function of the "With" keyword

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Given the code below, what does the "with" keyword do?  I'm not very familiar with it, and I'm not sure of its purpose.

```
Sub NotePage_Load()


With Request.Form
```

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a shorthand... everything within the With..End With block will be treated as if something is appended in front of it.

Ex:

```
With Request.Form
  ["xxx"] = "yyy"
  ["aaa"] = "bbb"
End With
```

is equal to the following:

```
Request.Form["xxx"] = "yyy"
Request.Form["aaa"] = "bbb"
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Very helpful.  Makes sense, simple concept!

Answer (score 3):

`With` allows you to omit the part after the with and just use the dot operator - `.` to access properties, members and methods.

Answer (score 1):

With is the equivalent of adding `Request.Form` before any references in the with block.

```
With Request.Form
    Dim count as int = .Count
End With
```

versus:

```
Dim count as int = Request.Form.Count
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it acts as an alias to Request.Form

So you don't need to do

```
Request.Form.this
```

or

```
Request.Form.that
```

you can just do

```
this
```

or

```
that
```